# Fixing Error 0 problem while Installing/Updating Tweetdeck

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, adobe-air, tweetdeck

I keep getting Error 0 while trying to install/update Tweetdeck. Trying to update it after exiting Tweetdeck didn't work, neither did making Tweetdeck air installer Run as Admin. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens if the AIR/Tweetdeck MSI file goes missing. To fix this

- Uninstall Adobe AIR
- Download & Run the [Microsoft Installer Cleanup utility](http://www.softpedia.com/dyn-postdownload.php?p=18442&t=4&i=1%C2%A0)
- Get rid of any TweetDeck or AIR files shown by the utility
- Check that there is no AIR files within:  `\Program Files\Common Files\`
- Download & Install [Adobe AIR](http://get.adobe.com/air/)
- Download & Install [TweetDeck](http://www.tweetdeck.com/desktop/)